# Resetting password in authenticationApp

Tags: django, reset-password

I need the users to give their old password too while resetting the password using the link they receive from django backend. How do I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to be more specific when you post a question here. We try to give specific answers on specific problems. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you dont really know where to start at all https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.